# Vue CLI project fails to import CJS module

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm trying to use an NPM package in a Vue CLI project (Vue CLI 4 / Webpack 4) but Webpack is failing to import the module in a way I've never seen before.

The package ("[scino](https://github.com/swashcap/scino/blob/v1.0.2/index.js)") is a CommonJS module that has one dependency: [decimal.js v7](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/tree/v7.5.1) (which appears to ship a CJS as well as an MJS version, for what it's worth).

When I try to use it in a project, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Decimal is not a constructor
```

That looks like it isn't importing the `default` export from the scino package's dependency correctly. I've tried the ESM `import` syntax, as well as variations on the CJS `require` syntax:

```js
import scino from 'scino';
// or
const scino = require('scino');
// or 
const scino = require('scino').default;
```

I thought using the `require` syntax would tell Webpack to use CJS-style module imports, but neither seems to work.

Interestingly, using the package in a codepen works just fine... so I'm pretty sure it has to do with how Webpack is importing `scino` (and its `decimal.js` dependency).

How can I get webpack to import this package correctly?